# If earth span fast?

Tags: earth, xkcd

Imagine earth spinning at very high angular speed. What it would feel like at various latitudes from 0 to 90 degree ?

Like at 0 degree one may feel lighter than his weight.

At 45 degree one is going to feel strange force towards equators. Cars would simply try to move to equator even if turned off !

At 90 degrees its going to feel as if pole is trying to push you away !

But still can anyone provide xkcd type of explanation of all implications not just the force felt !

At what angular frequency life as we know will not exist ?

Comment: There might be a question in here... I'm thinking it one were to change "Earth" to some kind of a spinning spherical space station it might be answerable. Hmmm...